# Why does my modal not open in my django project?

Tags: javascript, django

I try to create full CRUD for my commenting, but as soon as I added editing and deletion. It stopped wanting to open upon pressing the add comment button. The modal doesn't open.

Its a newsbulletinboard, it has separate articles that is fetched by API. It is parsed and rendered unto the landingpage. Each article has the oppertunity for each user to comment.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-10 mt-3">
            <div class="row">
                {% for news_article in news_article_list %}
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 100%; margin: auto;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title">{{ news_article.title }}</h2>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ news_article.content|linebreaks }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ news_article.created_on }}</p>
                            <hr />
                    
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <!-- Stored comments according to article-id -->
                                    <div class="comments-section">
                                        {% for comment in news_article.comments.all %}
                                            <div class="comment">
                                                <strong>{{ comment.name }}</strong>
                                                <p>{{ comment.comment_content }}</p>
                                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                                <div class="justify-content-center">
                                                    <button id="edit-comment-btn{{ news_article.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-dark edit-comment-btn" data-comment-id="{{ comment.id }}">Edit</button>
                                                    <button id="delete-comment-btn{{ news_article.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-dark delete-comment-btn" data-comment-id="{{ comment.id }}">Delete</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr>
                                                <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on }}</small>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <button id="open-comment-form-{{ news_article.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-dark open-comment-form" data-article-id="{{ news_article.id }}">Add a Comment</button>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="comment-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="comment-modal-label">Add a Comment</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close btn btn-secondary btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Your form content here -->
                <form id="comment-form" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    <!-- Name Field -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="comment_name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Email Field -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="comment_email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
            
                    <!-- Comment Content Field -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment_content">Comment:</label>
                        <textarea id="comment_content" name="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Your comment" required></textarea>
                    </div>
            
                    <!-- Confirmation Message (Hidden by Default) -->
                    <div id="comment-form-message" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">
                        Comment added successfully!
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- Cancel Button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <button id="submit-button" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Pagination -->
{% if is_paginated %}
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">&laquo; PREV </a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'news_article_list' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link"> NEXT &raquo;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        function submitForm() {
            var form = document.getElementById('comment-form');
            var articleId = form.dataset.articleId;

            var commentContent = document.getElementById('comment_content').value;

            if (commentContent === '') {
                alert('Comment field is required.');
                return;
            }

            console.log('Form submitted.');
            console.log("Article ID is set to: %s", articleId);
            console.log("Form action is: %s", form.action);
            console.log("CSRF Token: %s", document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value);

            var formData = new FormData(form);

            formData.append('article_id', articleId);

            var commentName = "{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.username }}{% else %}Anonymous{% endif %}";
            var commentEmail = "{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.email }}{% else %}anonymous@example.com{% endif %}";

            
            formData.append('name', commentName);
            formData.append('email', commentEmail);

            form.action = "{% url 'add_comment_to_article' 0 %}".replace("0", articleId);
            console.log("Form action is: %s", form.action);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
          
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
            console.log("CSRF Token: %s", document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value);

            xhr.onload = function() {
                console.log("XHR status: %s", xhr.status);
                console.log("XHR response: %s", xhr.responseText);
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status === 200 && response.result === 'Comment added successfully') {
                    document.getElementById('comment-form-message').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('comment-form').reset();
                } else {
                    console.log('Server Response: %s', response);
                    alert('An error occurred. Please check the console for details.');
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.error("Request failed");
            };

            xhr.onabort = function() {
                console.error("Request was aborted");
            };

            xhr.send(formData);
        }

       // Function for handling edit buttons
       function handleEditButtonClick(editButton) {
        var commentId = editButton.getAttribute("data-comment-id");
        var form = document.getElementById('comment-form');
        form.dataset.commentId = commentId;  // Store the comment ID in the dataset

        // Fetch the comment content for editing
        $.get(`/EditComment?commentId=${commentId}`, function (data) {
            document.getElementById('comment_content').value = data.commentContent;
            $('#comment-modal').modal('show');
        });
    }

    // Add event listeners for the "Edit" buttons
    var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-comment-btn');
    editButtons.forEach(function(editButton) {
        editButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            handleEditButtonClick(editButton);
        });
    });

    // Function for handling delete buttons
    function handleDeleteButtonClick(deleteButton) {
        var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?');
        if (confirmation) {
            var articleId = deleteButton.getAttribute("data-article-id");
            var commentId = deleteButton.getAttribute("data-comment-id");

            // Make an AJAX call to delete the comment
            $.ajax({
                url: `/delete_comment/${articleId}/${commentId}/`,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(result) {
                    // Handle success, for example, refresh the page or update the UI
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // Handle error, for example, show an alert
                    console.error(error);
                    alert('An error occurred while deleting the comment. Please try again.');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Add event listeners for the "Delete" buttons
    var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-comment-btn');
    deleteButtons.forEach(function(deleteButton) {
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            handleDeleteButtonClick(deleteButton);
        });
    });

    // Add event listener for the submit button
    document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', submitForm);
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons have the class `add-comment-button`

But your selector is using edit-comment-button

```
var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-comment-btn');
```

so your button listener is not being applied to anything.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about that one. Unfortunately the problem still persists. I have corrected the post accordingly

Comment: Currently you don't have any listeners added to the open-comment-form button.